# Haskell: What does type f a actually mean?

Tags: haskell, functor

I have stumbled on this piece of code `fold ((,) <$> sum <*> product)` with type signature `:: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> (a, a)` and I got completely lost.

I know what it does, but I don't know how. So I tried to break it into little pieces in ghci:

```
λ: :t (<$>)
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
λ: :t (,)
(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)
λ: :t sum
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
```

Everything is okay, just basic stuff.

```
λ: :t (,) <$> sum
(,) <$> sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> b -> (a, b)
```

And I am lost again...

I see that there is some magic happening that turns `t a -> a` into `f a` but how it is done is mystery to me. (`sum` is not even instance of `Functor`!)

I have always thought that `f a` is some kind of box `f` that contains `a` but it looks like the meaning is much deeper.

Comment: `<$>` is just infix `fmap`: `f <$> x = fmap f x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functor `f` in your example is the so-called "reader functor", which is defined like this:

```
newtype Reader r = Reader (r -> a)
```

Of course, in Haskell, this is implemented natively for functions, so there is no wrapping or unwrapping at runtime.

The corresponding `Functor` and `Applicative` instances look like this:

```
instance Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a)_-> (r -> b)
  fmap f g = \x -> f (g x) -- or: fmap = (.)

instance Applicative f where
  pure :: a -> (r -> a) -- or: a -> r -> a
  pure x = \y -> x -- or: pure = const
  (<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
  frab <*> fra = \r -> frab r (fra r)
```

In a way, the reader functor is a "box" too, like all the other functors, having a context `r` which produces a type `a`.

So let's look at `(,) <$> sum`:

```
:t (,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)
:t fmap :: (d -> e) -> (c -> d) -> (c -> e)
:t sum :: Foldable t, Num f => t f -> f
```

We can now specialize the `d` type to `a ~ f`, `e` to `b -> (a, b)` and `c` to `t f`. Now we get:

```
:t (<$>) -- spcialized for your case
:: Foldable t, Num f => (a -> (b -> (a, b))) -> (t f -> f) -> (t f -> (b -> (a, b)))
:: Foldable t, Num f => (f -> b -> (f, b)) -> (t f -> f) -> (t f -> b -> (f, b))
```

Applying the functions:

```
:t (,) <$> sum
:: Foldable t, Num f => (t f -> b -> (f, b))
```

Which is exactly what ghc says.

Comment: Nitpick: in this case there is no wrapping and unwrapping going on "behind the scenes". The instances you mention are available for bare functions, so the `Reader` wrapper (which exists primarily to provide extra clarity and readability) is not involved here.

Comment: @duplode Yeah, I see that is unclear. I'll add that, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that `f ~ (->) (t a)`. To see why, just rearrange the type signature for `sum` slightly, using `->` as a prefix operator instead of an infix operator.

```
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => (->) (t a) a
                              ~~~~~~~~~~
                                  f
```

---

In general, `(->) r` is a functor for any argument type `r`.

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

It's easy to show that `(.)` is the only possible implementation for `fmap` here by plugging `((->) r)` into the type of `fmap` for `f`:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
     :: (a -> b) -> ((->) r) a -> ((->) r) b
     :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

This is the type signature for composition, and composition is the unique function that has this type signature.

---

Since `Data.Functor` defines `<$>` as an infix version of `fmap`, we have

```
(,) <$> sum == fmap (,) sum
            == (.) (,) sum
```

From here, it is a relatively simple, though tedious, job of confirming that the resulting type is, indeed, `(Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> b -> (a, b)`.  We have

```
(b' -> c') -> (a' -> b') -> (a' -> c')  -- composition
b' -> c' ~ a -> b -> (a,b)              -- first argument (,)
a' -> b' ~ t n -> n                     -- second argument sum
----------------------------------------------------------------
a' ~ t n
b' ~ a ~ n
c' ~ a -> b -> (a,b)
----------------------------------------------------------------
a' -> c' ~ t a -> b -> (a,b)
```